# fill half bgcolor of calendar square

Tags: php, html, css

I have followed this tutorial: http://www.phpjabbers.com/how-to-make-a-php-calendar-php26-6.html#comments to make a very basic calendar. My aim is to create a very basic availability calendar whereby booked days are filled in with a different color. I have managed to accomplish this however I would like to be able to indicate mornings and afternoons by filling only half of a squares background color like the following:

http://www.phpjabbers.com/availability-calendar/

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more in the domain of html/css than php. One way to accomplish what you're looking for is to simply specify css classes that style the calender days according to their respective booked statuses.

I politely decline to look at your supplied tutorial, so I'll assume you're using table `<td>` cells to display the calendar days. One way to accomplish your goal would be to create two images and use them as the backgrounds for cells that have the matching class:

```
<style>
td.booked_morning { background-image: url(lower_half.png); }
td.booked_afternoon { background-image: url(upper_half.png); }
td.booked_full { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
```

The same concepts apply if you were using, say, `<div>` elements to hold the calendar days.
You would simply use PHP to tag each calendar cell with the appropriate style.

Comment: +1 for including an example (i was too lazy)

Comment: @MrGlass Haha I'm not sure why I even bothered to respond as my first instinct was to downvote and move on :) Must be those new year's resolutions ...

Comment: I figure why not try and help the guy? we all had a time when we didn't know what CSS was.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to half fill an object with traditional CSS. You could probably use CSS3 to draw a colored triangle, or stick an image inside the div.

Personally, I would switch to using a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Use images for background. For example red.gif, green.gif, red-green.gif. Set default background for every cell in table (for example red.gif), then create 2 css classes (.half, .full) which will have background attribute with *!important* at the end. Now You can just add class .half or .full to any cell and it will be half-colored or fully colored